# Adding KendoUI to Framework7 App, Framework7 SparkLines

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, html-framework-7

I was trying to get a JQuery Sparkline to work in Framework7, 
eg "    $("#sparkline-revenue").sparkline(" but '.sparkline' will always be undefied, no matter where I added jquery.sparklines.min.js file. So this is mean to work in Kendo and of course both work fine in a normal browser.
But inside "$$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {})" its not seen, not kendo or jquery  I know 'var $$ = Dom7;' so tried '$'.
I just want to add a sparkline to my app, can see one just for Framework7. 
How can I have KendoUI and Framework7 to co-exit?
Or is there a Sparkline that works with Framework7?

Thanks in advance.
Doug.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make jQuery Sparkline work inside a Framework7 project.

If you're using AJAX pages, make sure you put `<script src="jquery.sparkline.js"></script>` on the homepage of your F7 project.  It won't be loaded otherwise.

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    onPageInit: function(app, page){
        $('.inlinesparkline').sparkline(); 
    }
});
```

And inside the page:

```
<p>
    Inline Sparkline: <span class="inlinesparkline">1,4,4,7,5,9,10</span>.
</p>
```

Here's a quick example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqRKXm